# Iterate over hash and only display duplicated value once

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
@table = [
  {"country" => "england", "home" => "team a", "away" => "team b"},
  {"country" => "england", "home" => "team c", "away" => "team d"}
]
```

I want:

```
<div class="row">
england
</div>
<div class="row">
team a vs team b
</div>
<div class="row">
team c vs team d
</div>
```

I ran this code:

```
<% table.each do |table| %>
 <div class="row">
  <%= table["country"] %>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <%= table["home"] vs table["away"] %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

The result is:

```
<div class="row">
england
</div>
<div class="row">
team a vs team b
</div>
<div class="row">
england
</div>
<div class="row">
team c vs team d
</div>
```

How can I remove a value that is the same as one in a previous loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Enumerable#group_by`:

```
@country_table = @table.group_by { |i| i['country'] }
```

And then you can:

```
@country_table.each do |country, matches|
  puts country
  puts matches.map { |_, v| v.values_at('home', 'away').join(' vs ') }
end
```